# How do I install a shell script?

Tags: macos, git, shell

I want to use the shell script [git-ftp](http://git-ftp.github.io/git-ftp/) on OSX but I have absolutely no experience using shell scripts. (I use git from the command line a bit and that's all)

What do I do with the files downloaded from that site?

Comment: There is no need to install them. It is just a matter of directly executing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to install

- Open terminal application.
- Drag git-ftp on terminal.
- Run
  [image]

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to do this everytime I use it or just the first time?

Comment: $cd /Users/Parag/Downloads/git-ftp-git-ftp-b543bd7
$sudo make install

Comment: Now you can use $git-ftp on terminal